# Why does fseeko() fail with EINVAL?

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, glibc, fseek, large-file-support

I need to add LFS to a C process which uses `fseek()`.
gcc and glibc are of version 3.2.3 and 2.5, respectively.

I made the following alterations:

1. added `CFLAGS += -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to the makefile.
2. I replaced the call to `fseek()` with a call to `fseeko()` (I also need MSVC6 support, but one step at a time).
3. I've changed the 2nd argument's type to `off_t`. `sizeof()` on the variable returns 8.

Here is as good a sample `main()` as I can get past our DLP and its output:

```
fd = fopen("large_file", "rb");
off_t offset = 1ULL << 32;
rc = fseeko(fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
```

`rc = -1 sizeof(offset)=8 errno=22 offset=2147483648`

Comment: Your question is perfectly suited for including an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead of verbally describing the code and the outcome.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Which OS are you observing this on?

Comment: What do `getconf LFS_CFLAGS` and `getconf LFS_LDFLAGS` return?

Comment: Does the file system allow large files?

Comment: @wildplasser I'm not sure I understood the question but the large file I'm using is in the home directory and `ls -l` shows a size larger than 2GB.

Comment: `fseeko` takes 3 arguments, not 2. Is this the actual code you compiled?

Comment: @interjay you're correct, I had to mess around with the sample code due to our DLP solution blocking uploading of code. I've corrected the sample to show that I'm passing 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below program, compiled with 
`CFLAGS = -g2 -Wall -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` works here (3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

(compiling with `CFLAGS = -g2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` and `s/off64_t/off_t/` works equally well)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
off64_t offset ;
int rc;
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("testfile", "r+b");
if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen" );
        return 1;
        }

offset = 1ull << 32;
rc = fseeko(fp, offset, 0);
if (rc < 0) {
        perror("fseeko" );
        return 2;
        }
rc = fwrite( "OMG!", 4, 1, fp);
fprintf(stderr,"Write(4) : %d\n", rc);

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a newer version of glibc. My version does not support fseeko(), I've turned to using [lseek64()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lseek64) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `1 << 32` in your example is undefined behaviour. It is likely to return 0 or 1. Make sure to convert the 1 to a suitable type before shifting it. If `unsigned long` has 32 bits as well, then `1UL << 32` is wrong in the same way.

Avoid `-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` and `off64_t`, since they just make things more complicated. Instead, use only `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` and use `off_t` which should then be 64 bits.

Comment: Actually, I'm forced to use `-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` due to the glibc version.